# Difference between page source & frame source in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

## Look at the image.

[image: The bug]

After clicking on view page source & view frame source, it will open the same page,

*view-source:https://www.bing.com/*

Then, what's the difference between View page source & View frame source?

Comment: It's a bug in Chrome, https://crbug.com/1085992

Answer (score 1):

When a page has both View Page Source and View Frame Source, that means that usually the right click context menu is being opened on an `<iframe>` element.

- View Frame Source shows you the rendered HTML for what shows up in the iframe element
- View Page Source shows you the full page you were served when connecting to the site's URL.

You can test it here on the w3schools iframe "Try it out" page. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe

In the case of how it showed up on your Bing homepage, like wOxxOm commented it definitely looked like a bug. It works on my Chromium browser now, so I think they might've fixed it.